# Specific grouping algorithm

Tags: algorithm, grouping

I'm writing a program to form tutoring groups given student's and tutor's availability. Availability is given in a list of blocked times represented by letters. For example, if a student gives his availability as [A, C, D], he is available during the first, third and fourth hours of the day. How do you make a function that takes a list of students and a list of tutors and gives a list of groups that maximize the number of students placed in a group?  I'm working in Java, but I'm more interested in the algorithm than the code itself. Some more details:

Groups must contain 3-6 students and 1 tutor.

Students can only be in one group.

The number of student's satisfied (placed in a group) must be maximized.
For example, suppose we have students 1-6 and two tutors, both available at times A and B. The students' are available at 1:A, 2:A, 3:A, 4:AB, 5:AB, 6:B. The algorithm should return two groups: [1, 2, 3, tutor1] and [4, 5, 6, tutor2]. This assigns every student to some group, and is preferable to say, putting 1-5 in a group and leaving 6 out.

Comment: "I want a function[...]" well, OK, but there is no free help: what have you tried? What is the existing code? etc etc

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling

Comment: It helps if you ask a specific question. "How do you ... ?" is much better than "I want ... .".

Comment: Well I don't really know where to start, there isn't any existing code that's interesting since I have no algorithm to base it on.

Comment: then frame this as an algorithmic - language-agnostic - question and accept language-agnostic/pseudocode answers as well (I guess that implies leaving out the Java tag)

Comment: Surprisingly (or maybe not...) most of the related questions on the right side of this page address this exact problem. Perhaps check there

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how specific to be with tagging, but I said in my question that my main concern is the algorithm.

Comment: Clarification: each student needs to be a part of exactly one group and groups are indentified by letters?

Comment: Clarification #2: you want to minimise the number of group? Maximise the size of the smallest group?

Comment: Clarification #3: Do you want an exact solution, or you're satisfied with a heuristic? I've got a feeling this might be NP-hard.

Comment: Yes, each student can only be in one group. I didn't specify how groups are represented, I used letters for availability.

Comment: My only concern is filling the maximum number of requests for a group, the size of any one group just has to be 3-6. A heuristic would probably work fine. The number of requests won't be very big (about 100 max) so even an NP solution might work.

Comment: @JohnClaxton so all you need to maximise is the number of students that _have_ a group - and the size of each group is a hard constraint?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak I edited my question, hopefully that answers yours.

Answer (score 1):

Below are 3 ideas to help you get started.

1. A greedy algorithm. Match the first student in the list with the first compatible tutor in the list. Match the second student in the list with the first compatible tutor in the list. etc.
2. Find the most "popular" available hour, and match to that hour first. Then next most popular, etc.
3. Find the least "popular" available hour, and match to that hour first. Then next least popular, etc.

Disclaimer: I am assuming that you are working on something along the lines of a learning/hobby/administrative convenience, in other words that there is not a lot of money at stake for your project. If my assumption is wrong, I would suggest that you need to study more about algorithms, or hire someone who has expertise.

Comment: This could easily lead to a large number of underfilled groups.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! There's no money going into this, it's just a side-project I'm considering for my job (I'm a tutor).

Answer (score 1):

You can regard this problem as a graph problem: covering a bipartite graph by a set of disjoint subgraphs while respecting the two partitions (students, groups) and maximising the cover of one partition (students)

I'm thinking of this heuristic:

- start with an empty solution
- while there are unassigned students and open (less than six members) groups:

  - sort the unassigned students by the order of free slots
  - pick six students from the top of the list (read the list from the top until you find a group that six students can attend) and use them as a group.
  - If you cannot pick six students, pick the largest amount you can.
  - If you cannot find three students that form a group, but you have two:

    - Find a third studend for that group that is currently assigned to a group that you can take from (more than three people), and use him to fill the group. Prefer groups that can be refilled from the unassigned set
    - If you cannot find a third person, take one from a different 3-member group. Recurse the search for his replacement in that group (or give up). You can attempt to remove from different three-member groups in parallel.
  - If you only have one student, see if you can fill any of his groups by two other people from other groups. If needed, replace them recursively or give up.
  - If you have a student whose all candidate groups are already full, look for a person in any of these group that can't be moved to a non-full group. If all replacement groups are already full, recurse.
  - If you can't find a way to shift people around to satisfy any unassigned student, finish

Note that this boils down to this:

Quickly find a solution that satisfies the most people (you could stop here). Then try to insert students by finding a chain of pairings that:

- alternates between used and unused pairings
- starts at the student
- ends at a class

Note this is isomorphic to finding an alternating path in a bipartite graph, and can be optimised as such.

Note that this may still fail to find the optimal solution, as it never replaces more than one person in a single group to satisfy a person.

The pseudocode above instructs to resort the list of students at each step. Instead, you could track the changes to this list and update the sorting order while making the updates.

---

Update: I didn't notice you wanted to assign teachers as well.

In this case, you need to assign a teacher to a group when you assign students to it. This will prevent creation of some groups, but if there is no free teacher, you can take teachers from different groups if you can assign a different teacher to that group. Again, it's just searching for an alternating graph, this time in the teacher-group subgraph - shuffling students around to free up a teacher doesn't seem viable.

The entire graph that you want to cover now has three partitions: students, teachers, groups. Teachers and students don't interact, so there are two layers: students-groups, groups-teachers. These two layers are independent except they must cover the same set of groups.